# How to fix syntax error in hibernate redshift query limit clause

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, amazon-redshift

I am upgrading Spring Boot from v2.7.10 to v3.1.2.  This has an implied upgrade of Hibernate from v5 to v6.

Applications are using JPA to access a Redshift database.  The library to access the Redshift database is

```
  <groupId>com.amazon.redshift</groupId>
  <artifactId>redshift-jdbc4-no-awssdk</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.45.1069</version>
```

A CriteraQuery is being used for query generation and to obtain the result set. This code snippet outlines the steps taken:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery query = criteriaBuilder.createTupleQuery();
Root root = query.from(<entity model class>);
query.select(root);
query.where(<Predicate of all conditions>);
query.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(root.get(<column name>)));
TypedQuery createdQuery = em.createQuery(query);
createdQuery.setFirstResult(model.offset);
createdQuery.setMaxResults(model.limit);
List<Tuple> tupleList = createdQuery.getResultList();
```

Using org.hibernate.SQL DEBUG logging levels, before the upgrade I see the end of the query syntax as:

```
from "myTable" mytable0_ 
where 1=1 
order by mytable0_"last_name" desc limit ?
```

After the upgrade I see the end of the query syntax as:

```
from "myTable" m1_0 
where 1=1 
order by 21 desc offset ? rows fetch first ? rows only
```

Which results in this logged:
ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Amazon Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "rows"

Using Data Grip I can confirm that Redshift does not like the new syntax.  Can anyone suggest on how I might get Hibernate v6 to use the prior syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to be the selection of the spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect property value.

Change from

org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

to

org.hibernate.community.dialect.PostgreSQLLegacyDialect

solved the problem